# How to pass an anonymous array of strings to a JavaScript function?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I want to pass to an array of controls' IDs to a javascript script function so it will switch control's enable state.

For example, in `C#` it would be like this:

```
func(false, new[] { "Control1", "Control2", "Control3" });
```

In that function I want to find corresponding controls and disable/enable them. For one control I do this next way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function switchControls(value, arr) {
        for (var n = 0; n < array.length; n++)
            document.getElementById([n]).disabled = value;
    }
</script>

<asp:CheckBox runat="server"
     onclick="switchControls(this.checked,
        [
            '<%= Control1.ClientID %>',
            '<%= Control2.ClientID %>'
        ])" 
     Text="Take?" />
```

How to implement this properly? Have I to use jQuery?

Comment: An array literal in JS is just a comma-separated list `[in, square, brackets]`. The weird thing is that you already have an example of this in your `onclick` handler code, so you already know how to do it. You are already sending two control ids to the function in an array, not one. So what's the question?

Comment: Seems like a bug in array indexing inside of switchControls.

Comment: @ajm: Still doesn't work. `alert(arr.length)` shows nothing

Comment: What does the call to switchControls look like?

Comment: @ajm: I answered your comment in your answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function toggleControls(value) {
        $('.toggle').each(function() {
            if (value) {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');

            }
            else {
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'true');
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<asp:CheckBox runat="server" onclick="toggleControls(this.checked)" Text="Take?" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="toggle" />
```

Answer (score 4):

No jQuery (or any other library) necessary.

It looks like your code will do the trick with a modification or two:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function switchControls(value, arr) {
        for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++){
            document.getElementById(arr[n]).disabled = value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

As long as your ASP statement passes in a Boolean and an array of IDs (it looks like it does already, but I'm not familiar with ASP), it should work. For example, your `onClick` could call `switchControls` like this:

```
switchControls(true, ['foo','bar','baz']);
```

Comment: Neither `switchControls(this.checked, [ <%= txtMinimalCommission.ClientID %> ] )` nor `switchControls(this.checked, [ txtMinimalCommission.ClientID ] )` passes as an array. Of it isn't recognized as an array by JS function

Comment: clientID is not a valid property JavaScript would recognize. You would need to have ASP render that out and then pass it as a string in your array. Something like `switchControls(this.checked, [ "<%= txtMinimalCommission.ClientID %>" ] )`.

Answer (score 2):

you don't "HAVE" to use jQuery, but it's somekind cooler to use it :)

```
function checkme(arr){
   if($.isArray(arr)){
     $.each(arr, function(){
       var currentState = this.attr('disabled');
       if(currentState == 'disabled' || currentState == 'true'){
          this.removeAttr('disabled');           
       }
       else{
          this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       }
     });
   }
}
```

usage:  `checkme([$("#someid"), $("#anotherid"), $("#anotherid")]);`

Comment: Your code needs to be modified to allow for a toggle to enable/disable the controls.

Comment: How to combine ASP.NET call `'<%= code %>'` and jQuery call `$("code")` ?